# Testing Redux Saga, using values from the action that triggers it

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I have a saga that works perfectly well, I call an action and include some data, the saga gets triggered, it pulls the values out of the action, does an API call and ends with a couple of yield put's - awesome.

I'm now trying to test that saga and hitting problems, I've written a bare bones saga and test to try and narrow down where the problem is.

The Saga:

```
function* exampleSaga() {
  while(true) {
    yield take('EXAMPLE_SAGA');
    console.log('what is the value inside example');
    const { value } = yield take('ANOTHER_ACTION')
    console.log('value', value);
    yield take('THIRD_TAKE')
  }
}

export { exampleSaga }
```

The test:

```
describe('Saga::Example ', function() {
  it('should take EXAMPLE_SAGA ', () => {
    const saga = exampleSaga()

    expect(saga.next().value).to.deep.equal(take('EXAMPLE_SAGA'))
    expect(saga.next({
      type: 'ANOTHER_ACTION',
      value: 'amazing'
    }).value).to.deep.equal(take('ANOTHER_ACTION'))
    expect(saga.next().value).to.deep.equal(take('THIRD_TAKE'))
  })
})
```

What I expect is that because I'm calling next() and passing an object (a mocked up redux action) that I should be able to pull the values out of that action in the saga.

What I get is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
```

One of the things that's frustrating is that in my app, the saga using this syntax to get values from the action works:

```
const { value1, value2 } = yield take('ACTION_NAME')
```

The problem only occurs when I try and test the saga.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works as expected. In your code you assert that `saga` is waiting for an action (not pushing it). Therefore you have to pass your value object to the next iteration:

```
// expecting that saga waits for EXAMPLE_SAGA action
expect(saga.next().value).to.deep.equal(take('EXAMPLE_SAGA'))

// pushing EXAMPLE_SAGA action and expecting that saga waits for ANOTHER_ACTION
expect(saga.next().value).to.deep.equal(take('ANOTHER_ACTION'))

// pushing ANOTHER_ACTION and expecting that saga waits for THIRD_TAKE action
expect(saga.next({
  type: 'ANOTHER_ACTION',
  value: 'amazing'
}).value).to.deep.equal(take('THIRD_TAKE'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just updated my example code locally and I'm getting what I was expecting now. I now have a slightly better understanding how to test generators :)